# sweetalert dialog box with textbox in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I am having an issue with sweetalert dialog box with text field in chrome.
It works just fine in mozila but does not works in chrome.
Alert box works but does  not allow to enter a value in texbox.

below is the jquery

```
function sendmail(val){
swal({
    title: "Send E-Mail",
    text: "<input type='email' class='form-control' name='email' id='email'/>",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonClass: "btn-danger",
    confirmButtonText: "Send",
    html: true,
    closeOnConfirm: false
},
function (isConfirm) {
    if (isConfirm) {
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var dataString = 'email=' + email + '&id=' + val;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../class/sendmail.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function (result) {
                swal("sent!", "Your Mail has been sent.", "success");
            }
        });
    }
});}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it's two things, firstly you're using sweet alert's input wrong. You want to change the type of the sweet alert to input.

```
swal({   
    title: "An input!",   
    text: "Write something interesting:",   
    type: "input",   
    showCancelButton: true,   
    closeOnConfirm: false,   
    animation: "slide-from-top",   
    inputPlaceholder: "Write something" }, 
function(inputValue){   
    if (inputValue === false) return false;      
    if (inputValue === "") {     
        swal.showInputError("You need to write something!");     
        return false   
    }      
    swal("Nice!", "You wrote: " + inputValue, "success"); 
});
```

That's taken from the example on the sweetalert [Website](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/)

Also as you're adding the input#email after DOM load you need to use something like jQuery's [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) functionality.